# Calling Azure API mgmt REST API to update swagger API schema

Tags: json, rest, api, azure, ibm-api-management

I'm trying to update an APIs schema calling the Azure API management REST API like this:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.swagger.definitions+json" -d @service-api.swagger.json  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subID}/resourceGroups/${groupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/clientnetdev/apis/${apiID}/schemas/${schemaID}?api-version=2017-03-01
```

I don't get any response from the API management.

The .json file is in proper swagger format, editor exported, and contains the necessary declarations:

> API Management currently supports both 1.2 and 2.0 version of Swagger
>   document for import. Make sure that, even though Swagger 2.0
>   specification declares that host, basePath, and schemes properties are
>   optional, your Swagger 2.0 document MUST contain those properties;
>   otherwise it won't get imported.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following things in your json swagger schema

1. In the swagger file add the schema attribute above tags attribute.

```js
  "schemes" : {
"https"
}
```

2.In the path configuration with POST type, there is an attribute collection called parameters. In the parameters array, there should be only one data with attribute ‘in’ as ‘body’.

```js
   "parameters" :  [{

"in":"body"

},
//invalid
{
"in":"body"
}]
```

3. In the generated swagger file, the query parameters won’t have the parameter definition. So add the parameter definition to the parameter array. by specifying in attribute as path.

```js
"parameters" : [{

"in":"param"

},
{

"in":"param"

}]
```